# Are there any other ways to import server data to MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, import

My Task:

1. move data (1.on remote server 2.text file) to MS SQL server.
2. Create a table for hosting the data.

My Solution:

1. Download data from remote server to local machine
2. Import to MS Access
3. Use import wizard of SSMS.exe to import from MS Access

Are there any other ways to import server data to MS SQL server? GUI and command line are both OK for me.

Comment: you should be able to use BCP https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: [Brand new article from Erland Sommarskog, published yesterday](http://sommarskog.se/bulkload.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this week, Erland posted a rather thorough article on [Using the Bulk-Load Tools in SQL Server](http://sommarskog.se/bulkload.html). A quick excerpt:

> If you want to import a file into SQL Server there are a number of options available.
>    - Write an [SSIS package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx). 
>    - Use the [Export/Import Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) in SSMS (which
>      uses SSIS). 
>    - Use some other ETL tool like [Informatica](https://www.informatica.com/). 
>    - Write a custom program for the load.
>   
> - Use any of the three bulk-load tools that come
>      with SQL Server:
>   
>      - [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx), which runs from the command-line.
>   
>      - [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), which is a T‑SQL command.
>   
>      - [OPENROWSET (BULK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx), which you can use in the FROM clause of a query.

These are essentially your options; but [read the article](http://sommarskog.se/bulkload.html) and the documentation for more details (as an example, [this MSDN topic discusses `BULK INSERT`/`OPENROWSET()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to import data using Bulk loads in SQL Server. Such as BCP, SSIS, or even bulk insert the data from CSV. it all depends on your data structure in the Text file.